# In node js how to get the result of the other module method in current module

Tags: node.js

ModuleTwo.js

```
exports.getNotificatiosById = function (notificationId) {

db.get(notificationId, function (err, doc) {

   if(!err){
     return true;
    }
 });

 };
```

In modulelOne i need to get the result of the moduleTwo method.If moduleTwo method doesn't have the database query function means i can get that method result like below in moduleOne

```
   var res=require('./lib/moduleTwo').getNotificatiosById;
```

If that db.get method has the synchronize method means i can do the query like

```
  db.getSync(id);
```

Is there any other way to get the result of my moduleTwo method.Now i'm trying like below.Is it correct

moduleOne.js

```
     var moduleTwo=require('./lib/moduleTwo');

     moduleTwo.getNotificatiosById(id,function(err,res){
        if(!err){
          console.log('Result of the 2nd module is '+res);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `getNotificatiosById` to take a callback

```
exports.getNotificatiosById = function (notificationId,callback) {

db.get(notificationId, function (err, doc) {
   if(!err){
     callback(doc);
     return true;
    }
 });

 };
```

Then call it like

```
 var moduleTwo=require('./lib/moduleTwo');

 moduleTwo.getNotificatiosById(id,function(res){
      console.log('Result of the 2nd module is '+res);
 });
```